# declaring double quotes in tm package R

Tags: r, tm

How do i declare a synonym for a double quote in the `tm` package ?

I want to declare a synonym for inches as `"`

I an trying to write something like this in my synonyms list

```
synonyms <- list(
list(word=""", syns=c("inch"))
)
```

but the three `"""` renders everything as comments , so how do i encapsulate a double quote within the double quotes in a `tm` package so that it reads `"` as an inch in the synonym list

Comment: try `"\""` this would escape the second " in MOST languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this instead:

```
synonyms <- list(
  list(word="\"", syns=c("inch"))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you use single quotation marks the rest of the line is not interpreted as a string.

```
synonyms <- list(
  list(word='"', syns=c("inch"))
  )
```

Though the problem now might be that a backslash is automatically added to your string to indicate that you really want to display only a double qoute.